# Grapich text gap not working

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I'm working in javaFx2 and Scene Builder, I assign an icon to the button in the "Initialize" method, that works perfect, but the graphic doesn´t have a gap between the text and the icon and I want it a little more separated. I putted various values in the "Graphic text gap" property in scene builder and nothing has changed. For otherside, I tried stablishing this value with "setGraphicTextGap()" method with the same result.

This is a capture of what I get in the application:
[image]

and this is my FXML file of the root scene, where the toolBar is contained http://pastebin.com/J7L7h5xC

Comment: Show the code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: hi, I edited to add the code and the capture